# Get Colorized spdlog output with qt_sinks

Tags: colors, qtextedit, spdlog

Ok so I hooked up the QTextEdit with spdlog. But how to get the colorized output from spdlog/fmt to show in the QTextEdit? Am I doomed to implement my own message handler for that to happen? Or is there a slicker way?

Answer (score 0):

I saw the Qt Creator output pane can handle ASCII color codes. So I pulled this code from its source code and added extra functionality(bold, italic etc). After that I take QTextCursor* from QTextEdit or QPlainTextEdit objects and easily parse color codes and insert into thise widgets. In order to use this functionality you have to change spdlog's qt_sinks.h header with [this.](https://github.com/mguludag/spdlog/blob/v1.x/include/spdlog/sinks/qt_sinks.h).
After that use [this helper class](https://github.com/mguludag/qt_ansicolor_handler) to see colored output in these widgets.

Example result:
[image]